# how to drag and drop from datagridview to richtextbox in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, drag-and-drop, richtextbox

As title, I want to drag 1 cell from datagridview to richtextbox ? I tried with my code but it doesn't work. I set rtb_ArticleTemplate.AllowDrop = true in constructor and I set EnableAutoDragDrop of richtextbox is true

```
private void rtb_ArticleTemplate_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string tt = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))

        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}



private void rtb_ArticleTemplate_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    String s;

    // Get start position to drop the text.
    i = rtb_ArticleTemplate.SelectionStart;
    s = rtb_ArticleTemplate.Text.Substring(i);
    rtb_ArticleTemplate.Text = rtb_ArticleTemplate.Text.Substring(0, i);

    // Drop the text on to the RichTextBox.
    rtb_ArticleTemplate.Text = rtb_ArticleTemplate.Text + e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
    rtb_ArticleTemplate.Text = rtb_ArticleTemplate.Text + s;
}



private void dgv_Xpath_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        DataGridView.HitTestInfo info = dgv_Xpath.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        if (info.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            if (info.RowIndex >= 0 && info.ColumnIndex >= 0)
            {
                string text = (string)
                       dgv_Xpath.Rows[info.RowIndex].Cells[info.ColumnIndex].Value;
                if (text != null)
                    dgv_Xpath.DoDragDrop(text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is this forms or WPF

Comment: Do you see the cursor changing shape already when trying ?

Comment: @Philip Stuyck : this is forms.Cursor change to shape circle

Comment: add some Traces to your code so you can see where you come in the code or use the debugger in the dragdrop method. Don't debug the dragenter, this changes the behaviour of the dropping.

Comment: I use debugger in dragdrop medthod of richtextbox but it never enter dragdrop method when I debug

Comment: I open wordpad and I input some text then I copy this text to richtextbox. It's work but when I try to drag 1 cell from datagridview to richtextbox, it doesn't work

Comment: Then that means that dragenter is wrong make sure you really return copy, bypass the check for now. Format is not text likely. Now it is ok to debug in dragenter just to inspect what comes in.

Comment: how I don't dragEnter is wrong? It just some line code. If dataformat not Text so Waht is it ?

Comment: use the debugger or some test code to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dragenter is wrong. If it returns DragDropEffects.None, it will block the drag operation. If you change your code to always return copy iso none, you will see that the dragoperation will succeed.
Use the debugger to play around a litte bit to see what is the format of the data that enters during the drag. Hover over e of DragEvents and inspect its value completely. It is the place where you need to solve your issue.

Comment: what your mean line :         private void rtb_ArticleTemplate_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        { e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;}

Comment: ok. It's work well.But I have still problem: How I can drag and drop in text in richtextbox? ex: I want to insert cell 1 fron datagridview to between string "We have" and "for it"

Comment: For that you need to know the caret position in the richtextbox.